# trying to stop a Python speech-recognition loop with tkinter gui

Tags: python-3.x, user-interface, tkinter, speech-recognition

>
Hello World,

I am currently building a robot (ApplePI) and of course, in order to talk to me it needs speech-recognition (SR).
The Python SR works fine so far, but I wanted to start it via a GUI with a picture changing button.
The Button changes the color form blue (start listening) to red (stop listening).

Im on Linux (Raspberry PI) with Tkinter for the GUI and Python 3

Now the Problem once I click the blue button the listening function (“zuhoeren”) starts and it prints out whatever I say. If I hit the button again it throws an error saying it cant find the microphone.
I know the button doesn’t turn red because its still in the listening loop.
And I also know the error occurs because I am “steeling” the speech-recognition program the microphone when it wants to start a new listening loop.

The solution would be to put the listening loop in a thread so the button turns red.
Once I hit the red button the thread needs to be terminated but before that the speech-recognition program needs to be told to stop after this current running loop. I have tried many different solutions but nothing seems to work. There is a function called stop_listening = r.listen_in_background(mic, aufnahme_start) but its not doing what I want.

Please help me, the robot is a educational robot for my kids and my daughter would love to talk to it by just pressing the button but I cant seem to figure it out.

```py
    import tkinter as tk
    from tkinter import *
    import time
    import os
    import threading
    import multiprocessing
    from multiprocessing.pool import ThreadPool
    import sprachchatgui #sql KI
    global pfad
    pfad=str(os.getcwd())
    stand = "17.11.2019 knöpfe wechseln bilder und spracherkennung 20:38"
    print (stand)
    rootlogo = tk.Tk()
    rootlogo.wm_title("knöpfe wechseln bilde")
    rootlogo.configure(background='black')
    XPOS = 0
    YPOS = 0
    rootlogo.geometry("+%d+%d" % (XPOS, YPOS))
    rootlogo.geometry("800x480")
    rootlogo.resizable(False, False)
    rootlogo.wm_overrideredirect(False)
    w = Canvas(rootlogo, width=800, height=480)
    w.configure(background='red')
    w.pack()
    import speech_recognition as sr #pip install SpeechRecognition ##sudo pip3 install speech_recognition
    global alexasagt,satz,zuhoeren_aktiv,stop_listening,r,mic,_FINISH
    r = sr.Recognizer()
    mic = sr.Microphone()
    satz = ""
    zuhoeren_aktiv = 0
    hincount = 0
    _FINISH = False
    global multip1

    def zuhoeren():
        if _FINISH == False:
            with sr.Microphone() as source:
                audio = r.listen(source)
            try:
                textgross = r.recognize_google(audio, language='de-DE')
                text = textgross.lower()
                return text
            except sr.UnknownValueError:
                pass
        else:
            pass
    def aufnahme_start():
        global hincount
        print ("start")
        Hin = zuhoeren()
        if not Hin:
            print ("sage was...")   
            aufnahme_start()
        else:
            print("du: ", Hin)
            buttonstart.config(image = buttonstarticon, command=aufnahme_start_handler)
            aufnahme_start()

    def aufnahme_start_handler():
            global multip2
            multip2 = multiprocessing.Process(target=aufnahme_start)
            multip2.start()
            print ("aufnahme_start_handler")

    def aufnahme_stop():
        print("stop")
        buttonstart.config(image = buttonstarticon, command=aufnahme_start_handler)

    def exit():
        print ("EXIT")
        rootlogo.destroy()
    def buttons():
        global buttonstart,buttonstop,buttonstarticon,buttonstopicon
        buttonstopicon = PhotoImage(file='buttonstopicon.gif') #zahlen
        buttonstop = Button(rootlogo, bg='red', fg='red',height = 250, width = 250,relief='flat')
        buttonstopicon = buttonstopicon.zoom(3) 
        buttonstopicon = buttonstopicon.subsample(2)
        buttonstop.config(image = buttonstopicon, command=aufnahme_stop)
        buttonstop.image = buttonstopicon 
        buttonstarticon = PhotoImage(file='buttonstarticon.gif') #zahlen
        buttonstart = Button(rootlogo, bg='red', fg='red',height = 250, width = 250,relief='flat')
        buttonstarticon = buttonstarticon.zoom(3) 
        buttonstarticon = buttonstarticon.subsample(2)
        buttonstart.config(image = buttonstarticon, command=aufnahme_start_handler)
        buttonstart.image = buttonstarticon 
        buttonstart.place(x=100,y=100)
        EXITButton = Button(rootlogo, text='EXIT',command=lambda: exit(), width=8, height=3, bg='black', fg='red').place(x=700,y=20);
    def do_your_threading_thing():
        global thread1,thread2,thread3,thread4,thread6
        thread2 = threading.Thread(target=buttons)
        thread2.start()

    do_your_threading_thing()
    rootlogo.mainloop()
```

Comment: packages/speech_recognition/__init__.py", line 161, in read
    return self.pyaudio_stream.read(size, exception_on_overflow=False)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pyaudio.py", line 608, in read
    return pa.read_stream(self._stream, num_frames, exception_on_overflow)
KeyboardInterrupt

Comment: please don't attempt to post python code or tracebacks in comments. It is impossible to read. If you need to add more details you can [edit] your question.

Comment: I'm sorry but this was my first post here and I had some problems with posting

Comment: It would be awesome if anyone could give at least a hint how I found fix it... Thank you so much in advance.